# Using HTTParty with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, httparty

I'm trying to do this with `delayed_job` and `HTTParty`:

```
HTTParty.delay.get('http://example.com')
```

It successfully saves to the DJ table as this:

```
--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod
object: !ruby/object:Module {}
method_name: :get
args:
- http://example.com
```

The problem is that it doesn't have any mention of `HTTParty` in that handler, so when I try to run the jobs, I get this error:

```
undefined method `get' for #<Module:0x007fff1095b9a8>
```

I'm using `delayed_job (3.0.0.pre)`, `delayed_job_active_record (0.2.1)` and `httparty (0.7.7)` in a `rails 3.0.6` app.

So how can I make delayed_job and HTTParty play nice together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code in an instance method.

Example:

```
# User.rb model
include HTTParty

# Get a URL
def start_the_party(url)
  HTTParty.get(url)
end
handle_asynchronously :start_the_party
```

Then you just call it somewhere else like:

```
some_user.start_the_party
```

or if you need access to the successful get request contents

```
some_results = some_user.start_the_party
```

---

**Edit**

If you're going to make it a class method, then the code will be like this:

Example:

```
# User.rb model
include HTTParty

# Get a URL
class << self
  def start_the_party(url)
    HTTParty.get(url)
  end
  handle_asynchronously :start_the_party
end
```

Then you just call it somewhere else like:

```
User.start_the_party
```

or if you need access to the successful get request contents

```
some_results = User.start_the_party
```

The difference is that `User.some_method_name` is called on the `User` model whereas `some_user.some_method_name` is called on an instance of the `User` model (i.e. the current user object).

Comment: Now I'm getting `undefined method 'start_the_party' for Class:Class`

Comment: Are you calling it as `User.start_the_party` or `some_user_here.start_the_party`?  Please update your original post with relevant code.